# Veins simulation takes long time to start

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using the virtual machine `instant-veins-4-7-1-i1` on VirtualBox with `Omnet++-5.3` and `Sumo-0.32.0`.

I have modified the Veins Erlangen example changing the configuration file `erlangen.sumo.cfg` and introducing my own Sumo scenario. My simulation starts correctly but it takes about 3 minutes to start when I press the `run` or the `step` button, while using the provided Erlangen example it starts immediately despite this latter scenario has more routes and more vehicles.

Why does my simulation take so long to start?

Thanks

Comment: Is this related to SUMO's startup time? Did you try running your SUMO simulation in SUMO only and see how long it takes to start?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I have just tried to run my Sumo simulation in SUMO and it works immediately and correctly. If you need more details to debug please ask. Thank you

Comment: This sounds hard to debug. Maybe the number of polygons is very high (the Veins 4.7.1 example uses SUMO's polygons to define radio obstacles in the OMNeT++ simulation). Maybe cars are starting very late in your scenario. Are you able to share your scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by modifying the `my_poly.poly.xml` file:

I have removed from the following line

`<additional xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/additional_file.xsd">`

the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` and `xmlns:xsi` attributes.

I have also noticed that in erlange.poly.xml is used the `<shapes>` tag instead of the `<additional>` tag. I have tried to replace the `<additional>`tag with the `<shapes>` tag and it works correctly.